# Magento não carrega layout

Tags: php, magento

Seguindo a documentação do Magento, não consigo alterar o conteúdo de um controller personalizado. Parece que o arquivo .xml não é lido porém ele não me retorna qualquer erro e a rota está funcionando perfeitamente **meumagento.com/default/home/index**

```
- app
-- code
--- local
---- MarceloWeb
----- Default
------ controllers
------- HomeController.php
------ etc
------- config.xml
```

HomeController.php

```
class MarceloWeb_Default_HomeController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

config.xml

```
    <modules>
        <MarceloWeb_Default>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </MarceloWeb_Default>
    </modules>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <MarceloWeb_Default>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>MarceloWeb_Default</module>
                    <frontName>default</frontName>
                </args>
            </MarceloWeb_Default>
        </routers>

        <layout>
            <updates>
                <default>
                    <file>home.xml</file>
                </default>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>

</config>


- app
-- design
--- frontend
---- default
----- default
------ layout
------- home.xml
------ template
------- abc
-------- home.phtml
```

home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!-- Root node for Magento layout configuration -->
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <!--Page handle -->
    <default_home_index>
        <!-- reference tag specifies the block where we a going to add child block -->
        <reference name="content">
            <!-- Our page content block -->
            <block type="core/template" name="home" template="abc/home.phtml"></block>
        </reference>
    </default_home_index>
</layout>
```

home.phtml

```
< p >Hello World!< / p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Já tentou fazer a chamada de um block já existente para ver se pelo menos ele ta chamando o home.xml? pelo que me parece, pode ser as referências dentro do layout que estão erradas